# How do you use FFmpeg to give unique title/track names (%02d) using -metadata when splitting a file?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

(I'm using ffmpeg version 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev)

I've successfully split a file (in this example a .mp3) & given the resulting files unique names using "XX_%02d.mp3" in the following command: XX_01, XX_02 etc.

How do I perform similar for the file's metadata title or track? `-metadata track="YY_%02d"` gives the file the literal track name of YY%02d. How can I get the -metadata command to accept the numerical coding?

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp3" -c copy -segment_time 500 -f segment -segment_start_number 1 -metadata title="YY_%02d" -metadata track="YY%02d" "XX_%02d.mp3"
```